# Xcode server bot: pre Scripts error Trigger Error: Trigger exited with non-zero status 1

Tags: xcode, xcode-server, xcode-server-bots, xcs

I wanna setup a Xcode server for archive my project, but i get a tigger issues that tigger error Tigger exited with non-zero status 1.

That is my scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
#make sure the encoding is correct
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# fix the path so Ruby can find it's binaries
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# echo "PATH: $PATH"

cd "${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}/ZHXShop/"

/usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose --no-repo-update
```

My Project named ZHXShop, also "/usr/local/bin/pod" can search in my computer finder, and i don't use Fastlane in my project

```
My env:
Xcode -> 11.5
Mac os -> 10.15.5
Cocoapods -> 1.9.1
Ruby -> 2.7.0
rvm -> 1.29.10
```

The end i hope your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `wait` right after you call to `pod install`.  You can add this as a Add Pre-Integration Triggers when you edit your Xcode Server Bot.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# cd to where your Podfile is
cd "${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}/ZHXShop/"

# add to the path, or explicitly add the path to your `pod` call
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
pod install --verbose --no-repo-update

wait
```

Notes I found on `wait`

> The wait() function suspends execution of its calling thread until status information is available for a child process or a signal is
> received.

Comment: Notes I've been gathering on my experiences with XCS:  https://github.com/roblabs/xcode-continuous-integration